# web frontend for C# unit tests projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

The project I'm working on has a bunch of service-tier unit tests using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethodAttribute. I want to look into some web frontend automated generation tool for these tests. I don't care if I need to use some other framework like NUnit. I need some decent way to have an easy web frontend for looking at test results, that also allows adding new tests in an easy manner.

After a bit of investigation I realised that we already have TeamCity for the builds. Do I need anything else to setup test browsing from teamcity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use [Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/), [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/), [SubVersion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) together to provide continuous integration.  Every commit triggers a build and runs all the unit tests.  The cruise control dashboard show build results, unit test results and code coverage for each build.  Is that the kind of thing you are looking to do or do you want some kind of web based ad hoc test runner?

Comment: i know realise that all these projects are being built and deployed to dev and qa using teamcity, so i guess the most effective solution would have to be using it?

Comment: I have never used teamcity but as a general rule I wouldn't recommend changing an existing system without a compelling reason.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous Integration systems normally let you do this and usually have a web front end.

I know that you could set this up using [CruiseControl.Net](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) (which is free), the other system that has been recommended to me in the past is [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) so I'm sure that could do this too (and its also free as long as you don't configure too many projects).